# How do you check if a row exists within a stored procedure if-block in Oracle MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, innodb

I currently build a database and write stored procedures for an Android app. I am long time programmer and created some databases years ago, but did not really work with stored procedures until now. The problem that I have at the moment is that I find no right way to check if a given string (specified by stringId) and a given language (specified by languageId) does not exist, and if a translated string already exists before I go on and insert a new translated string into the table **TranslatedStrings**. I looked up many similar questions and lots of other websites and although some seem to have had the exact same problem their solution did work for them but not for me.

Here is my current Create Procedure script:

```
create procedure `InsertTranslatedString`(in stringId int(10) unsigned, in translationSource tinyint(3) unsigned, in translationLanguageId int(10) unsigned, 
    in translatedString mediumtext, out insertedTranslatedStringId int(10) unsigned, out returnValue int(10))
reads sql data
modifies sql data
begin
    -- if the string id does not exists
    if (select count(1) from `Strings` where `stringId` = stringId) = 0
    then
        -- return error code
        set returnValue = -1;
        set insertedTranslatedStringId = 0;

    -- if the language id does not exists
    elseif (select count(1) from `Languages` where `languageId` = translationLanguageId) = 0
    then
        -- return error code
        set returnValue = -2;
        set insertedTranslatedStringId = 0;

    -- if the translated string already exists
    elseif (select count(1) from `TranslatedStrings` where `stringId` = stringId and `languageId` = translationLanguageId) > 0
    then
        -- return error code
        set returnValue = -3;
        set insertedTranslatedStringId = 0;

    -- if we are ready to go
    else
        -- insert the actual translated string
        insert into TranslatedStrings (`stringId`, `languageId`, `value`, `translationSource`, `createdDateTime`)
        values (stringId, translationLanguageId, translatedString, translationSource, now());
        select @newTranslatedStringId := last_insert_id();

        -- give back output parameters
        set insertedTranslatedStringId = @newTranslatedStringId;
        set returnValue = 0;
    end if;
end $$
```

The creation of the procedure works like charm.

I call the procedure with `call InsertTranslatedString(76, 0, 1, 'German (Germany)', @insertedTranslatedStringId, @returnValue);` Both stringId 76 and languageId 1 do not exist.

When I make this call I notice that the `if-elseif-elseif-else` block skips the first `if` (stringId check) even though it should enter its `then` block. The procedure however enters the first `elseif` (languageId check) which works fine.

I also tried out if-checks like these: `if not exists (select 1 from 'Strings' where 'stringId' = stringId)` but there the `exists()` function seemed to always return true not matter if the `select` returned a row or no row; the procedure would then skip right through to the second `elseif` just because I used a `elseif exists (select...` there. The actual `select` however does not return any row if I run it separately. Very confusing.

Here are the three referenced tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `Languages` (
`languageId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`nameStringId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`languageCode` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
`hiddenInSettings` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`languageId`),
KEY `FK_Languages_nameStringId` (`nameStringId`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_Languages_nameStringId` FOREIGN KEY (`nameStringId`) REFERENCES `Strings` (`stringId`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='contains all supported and automatically translated languages'


CREATE TABLE `Strings` (
`stringId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`originalValue` mediumtext NOT NULL,
`originalLanguageId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`stringId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='contains all language-independent strings instances'


CREATE TABLE `TranslatedStrings` (
`stringId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`languageId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`value` mediumtext NOT NULL,
`translationSource` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
`createdDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`lastModifiedDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`incorrectTranslationState` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
`incorrectTranslationReporterId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`incorrectTranslationReportedDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`stringId`,`languageId`),
KEY `FK_TranslatedStrings_languageId` (`languageId`),
KEY `FK_TranslatedStrings_incorrectTranslationReporterId` (`incorrectTranslationReporterId`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_TranslatedStrings_incorrectTranslationReporterId` FOREIGN KEY (`incorrectTranslationReporterId`) REFERENCES `Users` (`userId`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_TranslatedStrings_languageId` FOREIGN KEY (`languageId`) REFERENCES `Languages` (`languageId`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `FK_TranslatedStrings_stringId` FOREIGN KEY (`stringId`) REFERENCES `Strings` (`stringId`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='contains all localized and automatically translated strings'
```

When I created the tables I did not create these `KEY` entries by the way, they were created by MySQL Server. Odd that they only resemble some of the `CONSTRAINT` entries and not all.

Since Strings only has a single-column primary key and no foreign keys I'm puzzled that its corresponding if-statement isn't triggered. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You appear to have foreign keys and primary keys in these tables, so why care for all this pre-prep? Just try and insert the translated string. Then it either: works, fails because already exists, fails because string not exists, fails because language not exists. catch and handle

Comment: in thoery you don't have to write a SP for this a INSERT will do.. `INSERT INTO table (<columns>) SELECT <columns> FROM table WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE ...)`

Comment: Caius Jard, I basically want to know where the failure lies when I call this and other procedures via JDBC. I know I can also make these queries separately with JDBC but I just started this way. And then again this seems to reveal some other error in my database design that needs to be addressed anyway.

Comment: Eh?  Where did `stringId` come from?  Seems like the test is redundant?

Comment: What do you mean with "where did stringId come from?" Its a parameter to the stored procedure. I know the syntax is working, it works in other procedures. If you mean `\`stringId\` = stringId` then stringId in backticks is interpreted as a string literal and the later one interpreted as a variable.